# How do I instruct scanning Software to use Microsoft Outllook instead of Outlook Express when sending a scanned document?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have come across this problem before.It seems that certain Software Programs will instruct Outlook Express instead of Microsoft Outlook.

*I am using a "Brother"printer and the software is control center 3.
*I require that the program scan a document and send it using Microsoft Outlook
*In this case the default Mail program is Microsoft Outlook.

*When I go into the software and select the properties and mail sending options:

-It only gives me an Outlook Express Option.
-There is a dropdown to find a program to use.
-It obviously seems to be looking for an exe. extension.
-When I find Microsoft Outlook I cannot find an exe. file to select.

It seems like a limitation in some Software programs.
Please can someone give me some feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your default E-mail client to Microsoft Outlook?

If you cant find the EXE file, search your C:\ drive for "outlook.exe".

Good luck!